# What are requirements for Append API on ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, append

What are the requirements for the Append API on ArcGIS Server?

We are running ArcGIS server 10.4.0 I can access after getting a token the following services :

https://xxx/arcgis/rest/services/dev/yyy/FeatureServer/0/addFeatures
https://xxx/arcgis/rest/services/dev/yyy/FeatureServer/0/query

But the [append](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/append-feature-service-layer-.htm) API is not working, if I call

https://xxx/arcgis/rest/services/dev/yyy/FeatureServer/0/append

What I get is the information about my server in response

Comment: The terminal release of 10.4 was 10.4.1. Lots of important patches in that release.

Comment: Ok thanks but sadly doesn't answer my question...

Comment: That depends on when the Append API was added, and if the documentation refers to 10.4.1 functionality.

Comment: There is no reference as to when it was added

Comment: Have you enabled Append on the service?

e.g. https://yourarcgisserver.com/server/rest/services/servicename/FeatureServer?f=pjson

Check via the ArcGIS Server REST directory